# Ajax call fails when page change in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

With my pretty big Cordova app, I want to allow one page to kick off an Ajax Post message and allow the user to immediately leave the page.  In some cases, I get an Ajax error even though the Ajax message has been sent.  I'm having trouble detecting this case.

Background: Yes, I made a bad architectural decision and my Cordova app uses many separate pages.  When the user changes pages quickly, the Ajax Post message throws an error (even though the Post message is always sent!).  Unfortunately all the error variables (jqXHR.status, textStatus, errorThrown) are either blank or 0.

What I can do is use the cordova-plugin-network-information plugin to detect if there is a connection.  If there is a connection and the Ajax Post message fails, I can assume the user has changed pages.  But this does not seem like a robust solution.

Any advice?

Thanks much!

- Jon